# How to print a newline in c#

Tags: c#, printing

Using a `PrintDocument` and the `PrintPage` event, `Environment.Newline` is ignored, so the only way I found to print a newline is:

```
        line = string.Empty;
        yPos = topMargin + count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics)
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, _
            yPos, New StringFormat())
```

Is there a simpler way to print a newline?

As a side comment, printing with .Net seems to have regressed to an unnecessarily complex task. Why did they drop the nearly automatic printing that was in VB6 with the `CommonDialog`?

Comment: What do you want to do this for - surely a newline would be invisible?

Comment: That doesn't look like C# code to me. VB.NET perhaps?

Comment: what kind of app is this? winforms? what are you trying to print on? the form? a control?

Answer (score 0):

This book helped me a lot on a printing task, hope you can find what you are looking for here.

http://www.merrioncomputing.com/Programming/Printing-a-NET-developers-guide-Part1.pdf

Alex.